# Gmap won't show infobubbles when clicking markers (with View Module)

Tags: 7, commerce, location, google-maps

First some information:

Drupal Version - 7.41
GMap Version - 7.x-2.10
Location Version - 7.x-3.7

I'm using the gmap module on a webshop i'm creating.

I made a custom content type for this (gmap) which simply has basic fields + a location field I've added. So far so good.

I've added one of this custom content, with the locations I need added through  the location tab in the options. I've made a view that displays these all of these custom contents (there's only one, but still displays it) which is working fine. The  problem is that, one clicking on the marker, it doesn't show the information while I've set it up to do so.

The issues start when I go to the configuration of my GMap Location. I get these errors

`Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in check_plain() (line 1571 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kickstarter/includes/bootstrap.inc).
Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in check_plain() (line 1571 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kickstarter/includes/bootstrap.inc).
Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in check_plain() (line 1571 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kickstarter/includes/bootstrap.inc).
Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in check_plain() (line 1571 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kickstarter/includes/bootstrap.inc).
Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in check_plain() (line 1571 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kickstarter/includes/bootstrap.inc).
Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in check_plain() (line 1571 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kickstarter/includes/bootstrap.inc).
Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in check_plain() (line 1571 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kickstarter/includes/bootstrap.inc).
Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in check_plain() (line 1571 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kickstarter/includes/bootstrap.inc).
Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in check_plain() (line 1571 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kickstarter/includes/bootstrap.inc).`

So I'm guessing i'm giving in something which is an object instead of a string, which should be a string in fact. If I scroll down, I notice the that it says "Marker for " but doesn't give any content type after saying just that. I'm assuming that is the error? I'm also getting a few errors in my console

[image: errors]

I really have no clue what to do, if i installed the wrong version or if I have some wrong settings somewhere?

Quick edit: using blocks in my regions, not really touching the PHP code I don't think that's a real issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the issue myself through googling better. Sorry

https://www.drupal.org/node/2241573#comment-10493640

Some bad code at line 999 of the gmap.module file, remove this and it will work :)